# Single file based graph database

Tags: database, graphs

I am considering using a graph database as an application file format for my single user desktop application.

Is there a [single file based](https://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html) graph database? [The equivalent of SQLite](https://sqlite.org/appfileformat.html) for graph databases?

Comment: Well, at least a couple people have been [wondering the same thing](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10991751). One of the commenters there provided a link to a list worth investigating.